# Paypal payment with only credit card without creating account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I built an PayPal `HTML` button on Paypal site with some details about the item.
After clicking on the pay button the client redirected to paypal secure page

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" class="payPalBtn">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="AEYPTR4G22C">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

There I have 2 options:

- pay with PayPal account
- register a new account and then pay with PayPal account

Why I don't have an option **paying only with credit card** without regestering as I saw on others sites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your account is verified/confirmed and that you have PayPal account optional turned on in your profile.  Keep in mind, that not every country will have the ability to offer paying with just a credit card and not having to create a PayPal account.