# 'Pay with my credit or debit card' option is not comming in Paypal express checkout integration

Tags: php, paypal

I integrated paypal Express checkout in a site  for the Merchant account test@yahoo.com (its US account)

We have already enabled the option  'PayPal -> Profile -> My Selling Tools -> Website Preferences -> PayPal Account Optional' in marchant account

But while i redirect to paypal site  from my site  , there is only  two options to pay

```
1)pay with my paypal account
2)Create paypal account
```

there is no option **'pay with credit or debit card'**

How can i enable this option '**pay with credit or debit card**' so that guest users those don't have paypal account can pay?

According to some peoples suggestions, i added

```
'&SOLUTIONTYPE='.urlencode('Sole').
'&LANDINGPAGE ='.urlencode('billing')
```

into SetExpressCheckout calling

Now i can see two option

```
1)pay with my paypal account
2)'pay with credit or debit card or bill me later' .
```

But while click on the second option it shows a form for creating a paypal account

so How can i set an option '**pay with credit or debit card**' so that guest users those don't have paypal account can pay?

I am testing the site from the Country India

I also reffered the questions
[PayPal Express Chekout no pay by credit/debit card option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362279/paypal-express-chekout-no-pay-by-credit-debit-card-option)

Answer (score 0):

I remember you have an option to allow users not registered in paypal to pay on your website through paypal express checkout. If you enable that, this option will appear

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But can u mention the exact option.I am in very urgent

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18018094/paypal-payment-with-only-credit-card-without-creating-account/18023424#18023424

In above link, it saying that, not all country will support for paying with debit/credit card.If it is correct , can any one say India will support it?

Answer (score 0):

Check this given Link

http://www.digitalgoodsexpresscheckout.com/PayPal/Articles/DigitalGoodsExpressCheckout/DigiGoodsEC.html

Its Helps you lot.

Also Check the demo [link](http://www.digitalgoodsexpresscheckout.com/PayPal/Articles/DigitalGoodsExpressCheckout/App/cart.html)